# Rename [animal-crossing-ds] & [happy-home-designer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming two tags in the Animal Crossing series. 
Both tags previously had their name shortened to fit within the old 25 character limit.

- [animal-crossing-ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-ds) → [animal-crossing-wild-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-wild-world) (26)
- [happy-home-designer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/happy-home-designer) → [animal-crossing-happy-home-designer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-happy-home-designer) (35)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

- [animal-crossing-ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-ds) → [animal-crossing-wild-world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-wild-world)
- [happy-home-designer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/happy-home-designer) → [animal-crossing-happy-home-designer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-crossing-happy-home-designer)